# Adding __Secure to PHPSESSID

Tags: php, session-cookies

I changed it in php.ini to

```
session.name = '__Secure-PHPSESSID'
```

But, when I use session_start(); the only cookie is named PHPSESSID.
When I try to use

```
session_name('__Secure-PHPSESSID');
session_start();
```

no cookies at all show up. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

[From the docs](http://se.php.net/manual/en/function.session-name.php):

> The session name references the name of the session, which is used in cookies and URLs (e.g. PHPSESSID). **It should contain only alphanumeric characters**; it should be short and descriptive (i.e. for users with enabled cookie warnings). If name is specified, the name of the current session is changed to its value.

Try to use a name without `_` or `-` like `SecurePHPSESSID`

```
session_name('SecurePHPSESSID');
session_start();
```

Comment: Changed it in php.ini, but if I don't call it with 
`session_name('SecurePHPSESSID');
session_start();`
it still shows up as PHPSESSID... Also, none of my other flags from php.ini are being passed

Comment: @sharkondero Probably because you are editing the wrong `php.ini` as there are multiple. (Commandline, server etc.). Create a file that contains `<?php phpinfo();` and look for the path to your **used** php.ini

Comment: Although, when I pass `ini_set('session.cookie_httponly', 1);
ini_set('session.cookie_secure', 1);
session_start();`
everything works just fine